# TCP -- coinciding sequence numbers in multiple TCP connections

Tags: tcp

In TCP, Initial Sequence Numbers are set on a clock and are incremented every 4 microseconds.

Suppose (IP#1, port#1) and (IP#2, port#2) set up a TCP connection and with the respective Initial Sequence Number-s as 
ISN1=100, ISN2=500.

A millisecond after, (IP#1, port#1) and (IP#2, port#2) are setting up another TCP connection 
with the applying ISN numbers. In this case, the sequence numbers of the first and the 
second connections are likely to coincide.

How does TCP handle this? It can reset and thus re-synchronize a connection under 
certain circumstances along the way when the sequence numbers are odd (not synchronizing), but this may not cover every case.

How are the sequence numbers handled in such a case when these numbers of 
2 different TCP connections may interfere with those of one another?

TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each TCP connection is identified by a tuple of [ local address, remote address, local port, remote port]. The sequence number is part of the state associated with that key therefore it doesn't matter at all if sequence numbers overlap.

Your particular example is impossible. You cannot setup two different TCP connections with identical local and remote addresses and ports.